# How refresh page when a user insert a row into the database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, server-sent-events

i'm doing a little group chat that every message are stored into the database. When a message is store the page need to refresh. how can i do a thing like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Web Sockets to keep open a connection to the server. You can use the ratchet library: http://socketo.me/ Check the documentation to have a overview of this module. 
Also, you can check this page to have an overview of this revolutionary system http://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/websockets/basics/  
EDIT: 
However, you can use AJAX, but make it simple with JQuery. Don't complicate your code ;)
Ajax is simple to use with JQuery. Don't make a Text area becouse it is ugly. Make a  in your document and other in an appart document and call it using:

```
$.get("theotherpage.html", function(data){
 $("#localdiv").html(data);
});
```

Give a look at this page teaching you to use JQuery AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). With AJAX you can refresh parts of the page, without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to use ajax. I need to refresh a textarea when a user send a message. Or an easy way is to check when database is update and refresh the page with ajax